# Cannot find the Resolve<T> method in UnityContainer

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx), the `Resolve<T>()` method of `UnityContainer` class is used as follows:

```
var controller = container.Resolve<ManagementController>();
```

However, I cannot find that method in `UnityContainer` class definition. All I can see is this:

```
public class UnityContainer : IUnityContainer, IDisposable
{
    // Other methods
    public object Resolve(Type t, string name, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
    public IEnumerable<object> ResolveAll(Type t, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
    // Other methods
}
```

Am I using the wrong packages or something?

These are the package I've installed.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
```

Comment: What version do you have installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IUnityContainer.Resolve<T>()` is an extension method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextensions(v=pandp.30).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, put your cursor over the `Resolve<T>` method and then press F12 and it will go to: `UnityContainerExtensions`

It is an extension method and the code is [here](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/c15bfc469949a36bed9fcf84293c0246c03f19ba/source/Src/Unity-CoreClr/UnityContainerExtensions.cs) if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It's inside UnityContainerExtensions class. As @CodingYoshi mentioned if you do a F12 or go to definition , you will find the whole class.

Here is the class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

    namespace Microsoft.Practices.Unity
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Extension class that adds a set of convenience overloads to the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer
        //     interface.
        public static class UnityContainerExtensions
        {
            //
        // Summary:
        //     Resolve an instance of the default requested type from the container.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   container:
        //     Container to resolve from.
        //
        //   overrides:
        //     Any overrides for the resolve call.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   T:
        //     System.Type of object to get from the container.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The retrieved object.
        public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, params ResolverOverride[] overrides);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Resolve an instance of the requested type with the given name from the container.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   container:
        //     Container to resolve from.
        //
        //   name:
        //     Name of the object to retrieve.
        //
        //   overrides:
        //     Any overrides for the resolve call.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   T:
        //     System.Type of object to get from the container.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The retrieved object.
        public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, string name, params ResolverOverride[] overrides);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Return instances of all registered types requested.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   container:
        //     Container to resolve from.
        //
        //   resolverOverrides:
        //     Any overrides for the resolve calls.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   T:
        //     The type requested.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     Set of objects of type T.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     This method is useful if you've registered multiple types with the same System.Type
        //     but different names.
        //     Be aware that this method does NOT return an instance for the default (unnamed)
        //     registration.


public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>(this IUnityContainer container, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);


        }
    }
```